# Power BI - Scheduled Refreshes per dataset

Tags: dataset, refresh, powerbi, workspace

I have a quick question about scheduled refreshes in powerBI for datasets.

I know there is a limit on how many time per day you can refresh a dataset using for example Pro License.

But is it 8 times/dataset or 8 times/detasets in whole workspace?

That is, let say I have multiple datasets, do I have 8 times/day refresh for each dataset I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is 8 times per 24 hours **per dataset** for Pro (or 48 times for Premium, or 1 for Free), but I'm having troubles finding a clear statement for that from official Microsoft source. But you can easily check that - make 8 scheduled refreshes on one dataset, each one 30 minutes after the other. Then try to refresh another dataset. It should succeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AndreyNikolov, will do. I struck the same bad luck with their documentation sadly.